# Reducibility of $x^3+nx+1$ over $ \Bbb Z$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations, irreducible-polynomials, integers

For what values of $n$, where $n$ is an integer, the polynomial $x^3+nx+1$ is reducible over $\Bbb Z$.
My attempt:

When $n= 0,-2 $, the given polynomial is reducible over $\Bbb Z$ as $x=-1$ and $x=1$ are zeros of the polynomial. But I couldn't find whether there exists any integer $n$ for which the polynomial $x^3+nx+1$ is reducible over $\Bbb Z$. How can we proceed from here? Is the polynomial irreducible over $\Bbb Z$ if $n$ is not in $\{0,-2\}$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)?

Comment: Yes.I am familiar.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If it is reducible over $\Bbb{Z}$ then it has a root in $\Bbb{Z}$, say $k\in\Bbb{Z}$. Then $k^3+nk+1=0$ so
$$-1=k^3+nk=k(k^2+n),$$
which shows that $k$ divides $-1$, so $k=\pm1$. Solving the two equations
$$1^3+n\cdot1+1=0\qquad\text{ and }\qquad (-1)^3+n\cdot(-1)+1=0,$$
yields $n=-2$ and $n=0$ as the only values for which the polynomial is reducible over $\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: That's a nice approach.